# how to get the rowcount from the query itself (i.e. without mysql_num_rows() or FOUND_ROWS())

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL I need to get the count of rows aggregated by some columns. This is part of a subquery, so I need the result to be returned by the query iself.

In this example query:

```
mysql> select count(*) from data_cst where target_name_id=208082 and
wafer_id=425845 group by target_name_id,wafer_id,lot_id,data_file_id;

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       12 |
|       12 |
|       12 |
|       12 |
+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The result I need is 4 (i.e there were 4 distinct groups of target_name_id,wafer_id,lot_id,data_file_id). How can I get that?

Just to be clear, this will be a subquery, so I can't use mysql_num_rows() or FOUND_ROWS() after the fact. I need the result returned from the query.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in that context.

Comment: So you need to have this '4' as a one more column for this query?

Comment: @mudalov - I want 4 to be the only thing returned from this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(distinct lot_id,data_file_id) 
  from data_cst 
 where target_name_id=208082 
   and wafer_id=425845;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need. I didn't know you could have multiple columns in a distinct. I was sure I tried that and got an error. But it works, so I must have had some other issue.

Comment: My issue before was that I had parans around the columns in the distinct, e.g. count(distinct(lot_id,data_file_id)) - that gave me the error 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)' which made me think you can't have multiple columns in a distinct. But without the parans it works.

Comment: hmm.  that looks like a parser bug to me

Answer (score 0):

Use nested queries.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
(
  select count(*) AS cnt from data_cst
  where target_name_id=208082 and wafer_id=425845
  group by target_name_id,wafer_id,lot_id,data_file_id
)
  AS data;
```